# JavaScript: string.replace() does not work, what is the problem?

Tags: javascript

I've tried everything, but my code doesn't work. I don't know why.

Here is it:

```
var table = $("#cpTableBody").html();  
$("#cpTableBody").html('');

var tmpContent = "";
for (i=0; i<cpData.length; i++) {
  var tmpTable = table;
  tmpTable.replace(/{firstname}/g, cpData[i].contact_person.firstname);
  tmpTable.replace(/{lastname}/g, cpData[i].contact_person.lastname);
  tmpContent += tmpTable;
}

$("#cpTableBody").html(tmpContent);
```

Comment: `table` never changes so `var tmpTable = table;` in the loop seems to be pointless reassignment, and that further implies that `{firstname}` and `{lastname}` are going to be replaced in the first loop iteration and all other iterations will do nothing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

easy answer... you're not setting `tmpTable = tmpTable.replace`... like so:

```
var tmpContent = ""; 
for (i=0; i<cpData.length; i++) {   
    var tmpTable = table;   
    tmpTable = tmpTable.replace(/firstname/g, cpData[i].contact_person.firstname + "");   
    tmpTable = tmpTable.replace(/{lastname}/g, cpData[i].contact_person.lastname + "");   
    tmpContent += tmpTable; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) 8 hours of coding make me a headache ;)

Comment: no problem. don't forget to mark this as the answer by clicking the checkmark on this post :)  It will also help you when you ask more questions on this site because your "answer rate" will be 100% and encourage people to post.